# Move SKSpriteNode on Touch to create Button effect

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am currently creating the main menu of a mobile game, and it works fine however To make it look nicer I would like to add an effect when I touch one of my SKSpriteNodes which is an image of a button. I would like it to slightly move down then back up before transitioning to the game, im having some difficulty. Currently when the button is pressed it changed scenes to the game scene.

```
class MainMenuScene: SKScene{
    let startGame = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "StartButton")
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Menu") 
        background.size = self.size
        background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y:self.size.height/2)
        background.zPosition = 0
        self.addChild(background)


        startGame.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.6)
        startGame.zPosition = 1
        startGame.name = "startButton"
        self.addChild(startGame)


}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{

        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
        let nodeITapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)


        if nodeITapped.name == "startButton" {

            let sceneToMoveTo = GameScene(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)
        }

    }
}








}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your logic in the function [touchesEnded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621084-touchesended) and then you call a [SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction) in your button, passing the moveToScene logic as completion.
Something like:

```
var shouldMoveToNewScene: Bool = False

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

for touch: AnyObject in touches{

    let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
    let nodeITapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)

    shouldMoveToNewScene = nodeITapped.name == "startButton" ? True : False

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard shouldMoveToNewScene, touces.count == 1 else { return }

    startButton.run(myAnimation, completion: {
        moveToScene()
    })
}

private func moveToScene() {
    //do your transition scene logic here
{
```

I haven't tried it yet, but hopefully you could get the idea.

If you're not familiar with [SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction) you should consider follow this [guide](https://hackernoon.com/a-guide-to-spritekit-actions-c20b079f5398).